# How can I pass a Float32Array to a worker in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, worker, transferable

I have a `Float32Array` that I want to pass to a `Worker` more precisely an `AudioWorkletProcessor`. I can pass it in Chrome but firefox don't accept the type as a Transferable object.
I found a solution which is to stringify the whole array as so:

`JSON.stringify( Array.from( this.audioBuffer.getChannelData( i ) ) )`

now the problem is depending on the length of the audio buffer the process is pretty expensive and during the execution the main thread get stucked.

Any alternatives for example convert a `Float32Array` to an `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: Try [the buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects)? I.e. `this.audioBuffer.getChannelData(i).buffer`

Comment: @Ry- Many many thanks now the problem is that it says the buffer is detached any ideas?

Comment: @Ry- I've added a slice() and seems it fixes the issue, I'll keep you informed and if I manage to make it work you can post an answer I wil upvote it.Thanks again

Comment: @Ry- it worked many thanks you can add your answer if you want